# NodeJS and Python-Shell .run function doesn't print STDOUT

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, shell

I'm using NodeJS, and a Python script.

I need to get results from my python script, for that, I use Python-Shell.
See the documentation at this link :

```
github.com/extrabacon/python-shell
```

I can get prints by using pythonShell.on and pythonShell.end.

The problem is that I can't send args with this method

Then I use `pythonShell.run`!

I can send args but it doesn't return prints while it should ....

Can you help to get my prints ?

You can see my short code below, it's a simple code, just to make it work.

```
var pythonShell = require('python-shell');

app.post('/index/generator/',urlencodedParser, function (req,res){
  var options = {   
    mode: 'JSON',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    scriptPath: './generator',
    args: ['hello','bye']
  };

  pythonShell.run('generator.py', options, function (err, results) {    
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Message %j ",results);
  });
})
```

Here the python code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

print(sys.argv[1]+' '+sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use child_process,

1. make python file executable

   `chmod +x generator.py`
2. spawn child process

```

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('./generator.py', ['hello', 'world']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});
```

```

then use process.send to communicate with parent process

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works, so I will use your method if nobody can find the solution of pythonShell.run.